# modified 3SUM algorithm doesn't work well with floating point

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, floating-point

So I've been attempting to solve the 3SUM problem and the following is my algorithm

```
def findThree(seq, goal):
    for x in range(len(seq)-1):

        left = x+1
        right = len(seq)-1

        while (left < right):
            tmp = seq[left] + seq[right] + seq[x]
            if tmp > goal:
                right -= 1
            elif tmp < goal:
                left += 1
            else:
                return [seq[left],seq[right],seq[x]]
```

As you can see it's a really generic algorithm that solves it in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The problem I've been experiencing is that this algorithm doesn't seem to like working with floating point numbers.

To test that my theory is right, I gave it the following two array

```
FloatingArr = [89.95, 120.0, 140.0, 179.95, 199.95, 259.95, 259.95, 259.95, 320.0, 320.0]
IntArr = [89, 120, 140, 179, 199, 259, 259, 259, 320, 320]


findThree(FloatingArr, 779.85) // I want it to return [259.95, 259.95, 259,95]
>> None // Fail
findThree(FloatingArr, 777) // I want it to return [259,259,259]
>> [259, 259, 259] // Success
```

The algorithm does work, but it doesn't seem to work well with floating point numbers. What can I do to fix this?

For additional information, my first array is originally a list of string of prices, but in order to do math with them, I had to strip the "$" sign off. My approach in doing so is this

```
for x in range(len(prices)):
    prices[x] = float(prices[x][1:]) // return all the prices without the "$" sign. Casting them to float.
```

If there is a much better way, please let me know. I feel as if this problem is not really about **findThree()** but rather how I modified the original prices array.

Edit: Seeing that it is indeed a floating point problem, I guess my next question would be what is the best way to convert a string to int after I strip off the "$" ?

Comment: `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. Read up on [floating point rounding issues](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/).

Comment: How are prices initially stored(what format is used)?

Comment: @user2040251 originally it is something like this ['$120.00', '$140.00', '$179.95', '$199.95', '$259.95', '$259.95', '$259.95', '$320.00', '$320.00', '$89.95']

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because numbers like `89.95` typically cannot be stored exactly (because the base-two representation of `0.95` is a repeating decimal).

In general, with dealing with floating-point numbers, instead of comparing for exact equality via `==`, you want to check if the numbers are "close enough" to be considered equal; typically done with `abs(a - b) < SOME_THRESHOLD`. The exact value of `SOME_THRESHOLD` depends on how accurate you want to be, and typically requires trial and error to get a good value.

In your specific case, because you're working with dollars and cents, you can simply convert to cents by multiplying by 100 and rounding to an integer (via `round`, because `int` will round ie 7.999999 to 7). Then, your set of numbers will just be integers, solving the rounding problem.

Comment: Multiplying by 100 might not be enough due to issues like `0.07 * 100 != 7.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your prices from string to integers instead of converting them to floats. Let's assume that all prices have at most `k` digits after the decimal point(in initial string representation). Then `10^k * price` is always a whole number. So you completely can get rid of floating-point computations.

Example: if there are at most two digits after the decimal point, `$2.10` becomes `210` and `$2.2` becomes `220`. There is no need to use float even in intermediate computations because you can shift decimal point by two positions to the right(appending zeros if necessary) and then convert a string directly to an integer.

Here is an example of convert function:

```
def convert(price, max_digits):
    """ price - a string representation of the price
        max_digits - maximum number of digits after a decimal point
                     among all prices
    """
    parts = price[1:].split('.')
    if len(parts) == 2 and len(parts[1]) > 0:
        return int(parts[0]) * 10 ** max_digits + \
               int(parts[1]) * 10 ** (max_digits - len(parts[1]))
    else:
        return int(parts[0]) * 10 ** max_digits
```